# To call user's of microsoft teams from external system

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I would like to implement functionality where on event on external application, needs to trigger a automatic call for meeting from Microsoft teams to specified users.

Is any API or method with which we can implement it.

Comment: Could you please try using [Create Online meeting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-onlinemeetings?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) API to create a teams meeting and use the link to initiate a call from external system to Teams.

Comment: @Gousia-MSFT Thank you for your update. I have achieved it using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http.
But now I want to fetch conversation of created meeting with API. Any suggestion?